# Авторизация в Angular - как обработать ответ от сервера?

Tags: angularjs, http, авторизация

Добрый день!

Сразу прошу извинить, если вопрос тупой. Не могу понять, или запутался, окажите поддержку.

Приложение "Sigin" обращается к серверу для получения успешного ответа и Токена, и использования его в дальнейшем при каждом доп запросе.

```
app.controller('SigninFormController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {
$scope.user = {};
$scope.authError = null;
$scope.login = function() {
  $scope.authError = null;
  // Try to login
  $http({
    method:'POST', 
    url:'https://mywebsite.com/api/login', 
    params: {
      'number':$scope.user.number, 
      'password':$scope.user.password}
    })
  .then(function(response) {
    if ( response.data.success === false ) {
      $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
    } 
    else{
      $state.go('app.dashboard');
    }
  }, function(x) {
    $scope.authError = 'Login or Email no right';
  });
};  }]);
```

Ответ от сервера вида:

```
{"success":"false","result":"wrong email or password"}
{"success":"true","result":"выдается jwttoken"}
```

Как сделать редирект при "false" на $scope.authError, а при true на любую страницу (в моем случае  dashboard)?

Перепробовал разные варианты, но проще всего только по статусу 500 или 200.

Comment: У Вас уже есть код для редиректа `$state.go('app.dashboard');`, используйте его. Или я не совсем понимаю что Вы хотите.

Comment: Дело в том, что при такой структуре 
.then(function(response) {
    if ( response.data.success === false ) {
      $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
    } 
    else{
      $state.go('app.dashboard');
    }

вот эта часть "response.data.success == false/true"  не работает. Переход осуществляется и при False, и при True. При этом ошибки не выводится. 
Т.е. данные Клиент получает всегда и делает переход. А надо получить  success c определнным аргументом, например, success=false. Значит если  false, то на ошибку, если true то переход.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так:

На сервере отдавать вместо `result` `token`
У вас есть JWT, я понял за этим стоит Laravel (наверное)
Поставьте satellizer
Настройка `$authProvider.loginUrl = 'url';`
и пользуйтесь

```
var user = {
  email: $scope.email,
  password: $scope.password
};

$auth.login(user)
  .then(function(response) {
    // Redirect user here after a successful log in.
  })
  .catch(function(response) {
    // Handle errors here, such as displaying a notification
    // for invalid email and/or password.
  });
```

Нужен редирект, окей

```
$location.path('url');
```

Comment: Использование satellizer не предусмотрено в нашем проекте. Просто потому что не нужен. 
Весь вопрос как интерпретировать полученный в "success" ответ и от него плясать. 

response.success == false или true  - не дает результатов. Ошибка игнорируется, сразу идет переход  $state.go('app.dashboard')

Comment: @Ch.Alexey Что показывает дебаг панель запросов ? Какой ответ сервера ?

Comment: status = 200 OK на оба запроса. 
при этом ответы от сервера, естественно разные.

Answer (score 1):

думаю не актуально, но может кому нибудь пригодиться: в "success" приходит строка, а проверяете на boolean, поэтому response.data.success === false никогда не сработает